# What does "leave work until the last minute" mean?

Tags: phrases

I saw a new phrase today in ''Interchange'' Book #2 page 21:

> **Some people leave work until the last minute, this is a bad habit that can cause trouble.**

What does this phrase mean?

Comment: Please provide a source and if possible a link to the source of the quote.  Please don't quote random sentences without giving their context.

Comment: It is in my `Interchange Book #2 page 21` I think I am not allowed to put a picture here due to the copyright!

Comment: Incidentally, the punctuation is wrong. The comma should be a semicolon or the two fragments should be split into separate sentences.

Comment: That's fine I've updated the question.  By the way, a short quote is permitted under copyright law of "fair dealing".  The link is https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pSt19CZv0L8C&pg=PA21&dq=Some+people+leave+work+until+the+last+minute,+this+is+a+bad+habit+that+can+cause+trouble.&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjur9S_uYjrAhWtWhUIHU2UCP0QuwUwAHoECAIQCQ#v=onepage  And we notice that you have changed the quote.  Don't do that.  Quote exactly letter for letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase word "leave" has several meanings. I can mean "depart / go away from".  But in this sentence it means "allow to remain".  It means the same as "I ate my fish, but left my chips".

So in this sense it means "avoid, or not do, a task"

Until the last minute means the lastest possible time to do the work:

> Some people avoid doing a task until it is nearly too late (and so have to rush)...

Answer (score 0):

This phrase means that some people delay doing their work until right before the deadline. If you "leave something until the last minute," you procrastinate, or delay, working on something until the last minute, or the latest time you can possibly finish whatever it is you are working on.

For example, if I tell my dad on Saturday morning that I am going to have the lawn mowed by the next day, and I don't start mowing the lawn until late Saturday night, I would be *leaving my work until the last minute.* If I mow the lawn any later, it will be the next day, which is when I told my dad I would have the lawn mowed.

Another example is: on Monday morning, my boss tells me to have a project done by the time I leave work on Friday. If I were responsible, I would start working on the project as soon as possible so I could comfortably make the Friday deadline. However, if I *leave my work until the last minute,* I would not even bother starting the project until Friday afternoon, and I would be rushing to get it done before I leave for the day. I might not be able to finish on time. This is why *leaving work until the last minute* is usually a bad idea. If you delay doing something until right before it's due, you probably won't be able to do your best work or even make the due date.